# How to display default image if the image is null in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a image source, but if the image coming from backend is null then i must display default image or the image in the backend must display.
Can anyone help me to do that.
If the image part is null then i must display this image

```
"../assets/images/msg.png"
```

Console:
[image]

HTML:

```
<ul>
            <li *ngFor="let message of activeMessages" (click)="showMessage(message)" [class.activeShow]="message.id == message_id">
              <span>{{message.updated_at  | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
              <img src="{{message.from_user_image}}" alt="img"/>  
            </li>
          </ul>
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let reply of message_show.messages">
          <img src="{{reply.from_user_image}}"/>
          <p><b>{{reply.name}} </b> <span> {{reply.updated_at | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}} - {{reply.updated_at | date:'h:mm'}}</span></p>
          <p>{{reply.text}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Ts:

```
loadMessages() {
    this.service
          .getMessages()
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.messagesdata = data;
              this.activeMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true);
              this.closedMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == false);
              if (this.activeMessages.length > 0) {
                if(!this.message_show) {
                  var test = this.message_show = this.activeMessages[0];
                  this.message = true;
                  this.message_id = this.activeMessages[0].id;
                  this.message_show.messages.map(function(msg) {
                    if(msg.from_user_id == test.from_user_id) {
                      msg.from_user_image = test.from_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.from_user_image = test.to_user_image;
                    }
                    if(msg.to_user_id == test.to_user_id) {
                      msg.to_user_image = test.to_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.to_user_image = test.to_user_image;
                    }
                  })
                }
              }
              if (this.closedMessages.length > 0) {
                if(!this.message_close) {
                  var test2 = this.message_close = this.closedMessages[0];
                  this.message_idc = this.closedMessages[0].id;
                  this.message_close.messages.map(function(msg) {
                    if(msg.from_user_id == test2.from_user_id) {
                      msg.from_user_image = test2.from_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.from_user_image = test2.to_user_image;
                    }
                    if(msg.to_user_id == test2.to_user_id) {
                      msg.to_user_image = test2.to_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.to_user_image = test2.to_user_image;
                    }
                  })
                }
              }              
            },error => {});
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to follow your code, but this is essentially what you'll want to do (use the reply.from_user_image unless it's null then use '../assets/images/msg.png'):

```
<img [src]="reply.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
```

Comment: You could write: `reply.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'`. @ritaj: why did you change that?

Comment: If there is image in the console will it display that image?, if the image coming from from_user_image is null then the ../assets/images/msg.png must display

Comment: @ConnorsFan I edited it back to my original answer. Please upvote if it's the correct one :)

Comment: does that satisfy the comment i asked for?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni - The best way to know if it works is to try it. You may also need to do the same for `message.from_user_image`.

Comment: ya i tried but the thing is i dont have images in any of the consoled things so i asked

Comment: @Bhrungarajni - It will display the default image only if `reply.from_user_image` is null, undefined or empty.